# How to write output of class in python to file in readable formay

Tags: python, file, class, pickle

```
# Copyright (c) 2011, Mark Chenoweth
# All rights reserved.
#
 # Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without modification, are permitted 
# provided that the following conditions are met:
#
# - Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
#
# - Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright notice, this list of conditions and the following 
#   disclaimer in the documentation and/or other materials provided with the distribution.
#
# THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS "AS IS" AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, 
# INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE ARE 
# DISCLAIMED. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE COPYRIGHT HOLDER OR CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL,
# EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS 
# OF USE, DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, 
# STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF 
# ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.

import urllib,time,datetime
import cPickle

class Quote(object):

  DATE_FMT = '%Y-%m-%d'
  TIME_FMT = '%H:%M:%S'

  def __init__(self):
    self.symbol = ''
    self.date,self.time,self.open_,self.high,self.low,self.close,self.volume = ([] for _ in range(7))

  def append(self,dt,open_,high,low,close,volume):
    self.date.append(dt.date())
    self.time.append(dt.time())
    self.open_.append(float(open_))
    self.high.append(float(high))
    self.low.append(float(low))
    self.close.append(float(close))
    self.volume.append(int(volume))

  def to_csv(self):
    return ''.join(["{0},{1},{2},{3:.2f},{4:.2f},{5:.2f},{6:.2f},{7}\n".format(self.symbol,
              self.date[bar].strftime('%Y-%m-%d'),self.time[bar].strftime('%H:%M:%S'),
              self.open_[bar],self.high[bar],self.low[bar],self.close[bar],self.volume[bar]) 
              for bar in xrange(len(self.close))])

  def write_csv(self,filename):
    with open(filename,'w') as f:
      f.write(self.to_csv())

  def read_csv(self,filename):
    self.symbol = ''
    self.date,self.time,self.open_,self.high,self.low,self.close,self.volume = ([] for _ in range(7))
    for line in open(filename,'r'):
      symbol,ds,ts,open_,high,low,close,volume = line.rstrip().split(',')
      self.symbol = symbol
      dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(ds+' '+ts,self.DATE_FMT+' '+self.TIME_FMT)
      self.append(dt,open_,high,low,close,volume)
    return True

  def __repr__(self):
    return self.to_csv()

class GoogleIntradayQuote(Quote):
  ''' Intraday quotes from Google. Specify interval seconds and number of days '''
  def __init__(self,symbol,interval_seconds=300,num_days=5):
    super(GoogleIntradayQuote,self).__init__()
    self.symbol = symbol.upper()
    url_string = "http://www.google.com/finance/getprices?q={0}".format(self.symbol)
    url_string += "&i={0}&p={1}d&f=d,o,h,l,c,v".format(interval_seconds,num_days)
    csv = urllib.urlopen(url_string).readlines()
    for bar in xrange(7,len(csv)):
      if csv[bar].count(',')!=5: continue
      offset,close,high,low,open_,volume = csv[bar].split(',')
      if offset[0]=='a':
        day = float(offset[1:])
        offset = 0
      else:
        offset = float(offset)
      open_,high,low,close = [float(x) for x in [open_,high,low,close]]
      dt = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(day+(interval_seconds*offset))
      self.append(dt,open_,high,low,close,volume)


if __name__ == '__main__':

                      # print it out ### The below code is added by me
  ***with open("data.dump", "wb") as output:
    cPickle.dump(GoogleIntradayQuote('spy',300,30), output,protocol=cPickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
  with open("data.dump",'rb') as fp:
    d1 = cPickle.load(fp)
    f = open("data.dump", 'rb')
    loaded_obj = cPickle.load(f)
    f.close()
    print d1***
```

The above script takes data from google finance and print it out on screen. I have added code to write the same data to file

The file which is getting created is unreadable format.

can someone please suggest me better way to create file using this method?

Comment: You can use `csv` module: [CSV File Reading and Writing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html)

Comment: I tried but it couldn't figure it out

Comment: @IldarMusin                                                                                                                                             I Wrote this code                                                            `                          d = GoogleIntradayQuote('spy',300,30)
    with open('test.csv', 'wb') as fp:
        a = csv.writer(fp, delimiter=',')
        a.writerows(d) `                                                                                                           It giving the error TypeError: writerows() argument must be iterable

Comment: FWIW, the `pickle` file format is not designed to be (easily) readable by humans. The code you've added is messy & strange: you open "data.dump" in read mode and then open it again while it's still open.